# Trouble with static files on deployment server

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, web-applications, fastcgi

I can't seem to figure out how to let my Django app access my static files now that my app is on my deployment server and **Debug mode is turned off**.

I've used `python manage.py collectstatic` to collect all of my static files into a directory outside of my app and then added this line to my .htaccess:

```
Alias /static /home1/textbop6/public_html/beta/static
```

Here is the relevant code from my settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home1/textbop6/public_html/beta/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    forwardslash(os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')),
)
```

I keep getting internal server errors.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: And what might these internal errors say?

Comment: [Sun Mar 31 15:01:57 2013] [warn] RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored.

Comment: and: [Sun Mar 31 15:01:59 2013] [error] [client 66.249.74.72] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: So, that seems to be caused by the Rewrite rules in your apache conf. What makes you think this has anything to do with Django?

Comment: You are right, it has to do with my .htaccess file. I only started getting this error after adding the "Alias..." line above. Before that I was just getting 404 errors for all of my static content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just had to move my static content outside of my project's folder on the server. I ended up just putting it in the root so I didn't need to include that extra line (Alias...) in my .htaccess.